# Constraint layout's child aspect ratio

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How to make an image taking up full width on a screen when using a constraint layout. As i am using 0dp the image is only centered and not taking full width at the top of screen.Here is my code what i have tried...

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="16:9"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user_img" />
```

Comment: The image is centered..and not taking up full width...

Comment: Your specifications are contradictory. If you want the image to keep a specific aspect ratio *and* scale it to full width, then you cannot limit it to a maximum height.

Answer (score 0):

To set the aspect ration to height 
**`app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1`**

EDIT :

As OP want to set `maxHeight` to the `ImageView`.

Specify **`app:layout_constraintHeight_max="250dp""`** this should cause `ConstraintLayout` pick up your max height.

```
   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_max="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/attach_document" />
```